# SFTP connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp

I am having a trouble opening a session to a specific sftp.
I ran this command as per the steps given by the host to connect to their ftp.

```
sftp -o port=7010 -o IdentityFile=sftp_file_address username@ip_address
```

I tried running it on verbose adding the -vvv after the sftp.

Here is the output.

```
Connecting to ip_address...
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ip_address [ip_address] port 7010.
debug1: connect to address ip_address port 7010: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ip_address port 7010: Connection timed out
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I am entirely new to this, can you help me understand why this happened and what does the output means?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do a search for "SFTP connection reset by peer", there are tons of answers already to this common problem: usually the administrator, of the host you are connecting to, needs to restrict the permissions of your home directory, so just ask them to fix it if you are not the admin yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is described by the message `connect to host ip_address port 7010: Connection timed out`. That means that your computer attempted to communicate with `ip_address` (which I assume is an actual IP address that you've redacted) and received no response. Perhaps the remote host has been disconnected from the network, or you have the wrong IP address.